# 401 error for apps outside Rally

Tags: rally

I am creating a app that can be displayed outside rally. I created a login key for a read-only user as described in the documentation and substituted it for [loginkey] in the code below. When i try to access the app I am being asked for user credentials again. When i cancel the authentication dialog i receive a 401 error in the developer tools in the browser. Please find my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>LoginKey</title>

<!--App information-->
<meta name="Name" content="App: LoginKey"/>
<meta name="Version" content="1.0"/>
<meta name="Vendor" content=""/>

<!--Include SDK-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?loginkey=[loginkey]"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad() {
        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
                    '__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
                    rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
        var config = {type: "hierarchicalrequirement", columnKeys:["FormattedID", "Name"]};
        var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config, rallyDataSource);
        table.display("tableDiv");
    }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);


</script>

<style type="text/css">

    .loginKey {
        /* Add app styles here */
    }

</style>


</head>
<body class="loginKey">
<div id="tableDiv" style="float:left;width:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the name of the parameter. I was using loginkey for the name of the parameter while it was actually supposed to be loginKey